# How to save the XML file using powershell script

Tags: powershell, xml

I have an XML file with the below content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Topology>
  <SERVER1 desc="name of server1"></ICONIS_ONLINE_SERVER1>
  <SERVER2 desc="name of server2">PROJECT</SSCOFFLINE_SERVER1>
</Topology>
```

I have the following powershell script to get the contents, modify the contents and save the content of XML file.

```
#This will replace the values on the topology file and saves it
$xmldata =[XML](Get-Content \\10.10.115.16\c$\Deployment\Config.xml)
$xmldata. Topology.SERVER1.InnerText = 'Mydomain'
$xmldata. Save((Resolve-Path \\10.10.115.16\c$\Deployment\Config.xml). Path
```

The above powershell script will replace the contents and saves it. However, it is not allowing to save it. It shows the error as

Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the
[WebClient Uploadfile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads) command, as follows :

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$resp = $wc.UploadFile($uri,$filePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [New-SmbMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbmapping?view=windowsserver2022-ps) from the [SMBShare module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

```
New-SmbMapping -RemotePath '\\10.10.115.16' -Username "foo.local\bar" -Password "password"
```

From there you should be able to save to the file the way you're trying to above.